# order clause for varchar ranges

Tags: sql, database

I currently have a column in db with few ranges storaged as varchar, such as:

```
0-499
1000-1199
500-999
```

How do I order these ranges like the following:

```
0-499
500-999
1000-1199
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What you stumble uopn is a bad datamodel. Two solutions: **(1)** You don't care that '500-999' means 500 to 999. Then store a sortkey with the table '0-499' = sortkey 1, '500-999' = sortkey 2, '1000-1199' = sortkey 3 etc. **(2)** You want your DBMS to know that this is a range from 500 to 999, then store it such, i.e. one or two numeric columns (depending on whether you consider a range end be implicitely given by the next range start minus one).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be tricky, you can do:

```
order by cast(replace(col, '-', '.') as decimal(30, 15))
```

This replaces the hyphen with a decimal point, converts to a numeric value, and uses that for sorting.  This should work in just about any database.

This is not perfect, because it does not really order by the second number of the range correctly.  But the first number would need to exactly match (and for some reason, that seems unlikely to me base on your sample data).

Answer (score 0):

Order by the characters before the hyphen, converted to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use`order by` clause with `left()` function :

```
order by cast(left(n, charindex('-', n)-1) as int);
```

However, the preceding `order by` cluase has int conversation, if you have decimal value before hyphen then use `decimal` instead

Comment: Just doing that won't change the order unless you also convert to a numeric data type.

Answer (score 0):

if these are the only values:

```
order by 
case varcharcol when '0-100' then 1
when '500-1000' then 2
when '1000-1199' then 3
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #temp1(id int,range varchar(50))

insert into #temp1(id,range)
values (1,'0-499'),(2,'1000-1199'),(3,'500-999')

select * from #temp1 order by cast(replace(range, '-', '.') as decimal(30, 15))


id  range
1   0-499
3   500-999
2   1000-1199

select * from #temp1 order by cast (substring(range,0,charindex('-',range)) as int)

id  range
1   0-499
3   500-999
2   1000-1199
```